# How to run a PHPunit test suite in multiple different php environments?

Tags: php, testing, timezone, phpunit

I should run a [PHPUnit 3.7](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/index.html) test suite in different php environments: with different php.ini settings and even in different OS environment. I want to make sure that my test suite and the underlying classes work constantly when

- php.ini [date.timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) setting varies; and/or
- OS's internal timezone varies

How to properly do set-up the test environment in PHPUnit and in CLI (Linux)?

Comment: You want to have a look at Travis CI!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you all you want to is to change php.ini settings and maybe OS/env vars I'd suggest writing little bash script wrappers (or using your build tool of choice) to do the equivalent.

#### Using PHP 5.3 with a different timezone:

```
/path/to/php-5.3 -d date.timezone=America/New_york /usr/bin/phpunit
```

#### Using PHP 5.4 with another timezone and differnt ENV

```
export TZ=Europa/Berlin 
/path/to/php-5.4 -d date.timezone=Aemerica/San_Franciso /usr/bin/phpunit
```

---

This approach will also work with `process_isolation` if you use that feature as PHPUnit will be able to figure out what PHP binary was used but you **might** have issues with the "-d" parameters. In that case don't pass them to the php binary but to phpunit. (`phpunit -d date.timezone=foo`). PHPUnit will then take care of setting it before your tests run.